# Authentication Issue w.r.t Devops REST APIs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get the Pipeline run details via Devops REST API.

The API is working fine when authenticating using the PAT value within Azure data factory as seen below :

[image]

But ADF is failing with below error :

pan class="error">Microsoft Internet Explorer's Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.\r\n \r\n

when executing via Managed Identity auth .

[image]

Note : The ADF has project administrator permission. So doesnt seems to be permission related

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your PAT to a **Base64** string. Then, use the **Base64** string to call the Azure DevOps REST API on ADF.

Below is a way to convert PAT to a **Base64** string using PowerShell.

```
$pat = 'xxxxxx'
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
```

Comment: Hey, there seems to be some misunderstanding in the ask here :)   Basically the API is working fine when PAT is being used but we need to move away from PAT to Managed identity auth. So any idea how to have base64 string via managed identity being triggered in ADF?

Comment: @Nandan, [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?view=azure-devops) is the docs about how to generate an AAD token (Microsoft Entra token) for managed identities or service principals to access the resources of Azure DevOps. The token can be used to call the Azure DevOps REST API and Azure DevOps CLI.